# Serial TTA0: connection to Virtual machine | Weird characters and no input

Tags: virtual-machine, serial-port, emulator, com-port, openvms

I have setup a serial TTA0: connection to an OpenVMS Emulator running in virtual windows.
The console serial port is configured as follows:

1. TTA0.type="socket"
2. TTA0.port=":20000"
3. TTA0.stop_process="no"
4. ### TTA0.command="putty -raw -P 20000 localhost"

Then I connect to it from the linux Host :

[image]

Every first connection is not working, I have weird characters on the screen,it ends every keystroke with errors and weird text and it doesn't write commands correctly.
Then after 20/30 keystroke it works perfect, no more weird text and no more errors.

If I uncomment the local Putty config (lastline),I connect with Putty directly in the Windows guest to the TTA0: and all is working as it should.

I don't find why the first keystrokes/commands are not working, I can't run scripts and every time I reboot I have to solve that manually and then boot the system.

Update 12/16/2014:
Here is a better explanation:

1.Linux(Host)/OpenVMS1(linux emulator)

2.Linux(host)/Windows1(VMW-guest)/OpenVMS2(windows emulator)

all systems are up.
Windows host starts up, OpenVMS2 emulator starts up but hangs in console prompt; waiting for commands.
When i connect to it from OpenVMS1 using :

```
VMS1$console connect OpenVMS2 ( connects to TTA0: serial port)
```

when connecting nothing works for first 20/30 keystrokes as described up there.

Comment: What client are you using on Linux?

Comment: I am using Putty.
Connection Type : Raw | 
Auto wrap mode initially on | 
Disable Nagle's algorithm (TCP_NODELAY) | 
Proxy : None |

Comment: I did try again with the terminal, i can say that it's better than Putty, the console is back to normal after 5/10 keystrokes. But never ok from first connection.

Comment: ...which terminal? There are a few dozen, and aside from PuTTY, I've not seen _any_ Linux terminals that have built-in ability to make TCP connections (usually requiring one to run a TCP client like `nc` or `telnet`).

Comment: How do you connect to TTA0: from that other OpenVMS VM? Also telnet?

Comment: I added more info in the post up.